# Windows XP started lagging, sounds are crazy

Tags: windows, windows-xp, lag

my windows XP suddenly started lagging, sounds are crazy. It looks the sounds became "slowlier" and mouse movement is laggy too. The whole system bootstraps slowlier. Memtest OK, checkdisks are done.

Comment: Have you considered actually testing your hard drives performance, rather than just checking for bad blocks? Also, have you checked the event logs for any clues?

Comment: Check all your fans.

Comment: yep, fans maybe the answer, recently it started sounds at very high frequency

Comment: Appears your computer is getting too hotlier.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure it's going to turn out to be the OS; perhaps a recent update. However troubleshooting the hardware just to get 'that' out of the way it's a bad idea. It's good to keep a handful of boot CDs around for just this sort of thing.

Specifically a handful of Hard Disk Diagnosis tools on the [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) would come in the handiest right now.

And as for other handy disks to keep around, here is my recommended list:

- Ultimate Boot CD
- Knoppix
- CloneZilla (the CD boot disk, not just the program)j
- OPHorack

Hopes these not only prove to be helpful in this situation but many others for you in the future.